# Scrolling issue with coordinator layout when no data in recycleview android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I don't want to scroll when there is no data in recycleview with coordinator layout.
Check below for my xml layout. When recycleview is empty and after scrolling upwards, I am unable to scroll back. check images.

**fragment_detail.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorTransparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativeProfile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                    >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relativeVideo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        >

                        <com.malmstein.fenster.view.FensterVideoView
                            android:id="@+id/videoplayer"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                            />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/linearPlay"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/round_button_progress_bar"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            >

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imgShadow"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
                                />

                        </LinearLayout>


                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/relativeVideoTime"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            >

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnOnSale"
                                android:background="@drawable/round_button_progress_bar"
                                >

                                <com.spoof.app.customcontrol.CustomTextViewRegular
                                    android:id="@+id/txtUpdateTime"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                                    android:maxLines="1"
                                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                    android:textSize="12sp"
                                    android:textStyle="normal"
                                    />

                                <app.minimize.com.seek_bar_compat.SeekBarCompat
                                    android:id="@+id/range_slider5"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtTotalTime"
                                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtUpdateTime"
                                    android:maxHeight="300sp"
                                    app:progressBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                    app:progressColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                    app:thumbColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                    />

                                <com.spoof.app.customcontrol.CustomTextViewRegular
                                    android:id="@+id/txtTotalTime"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                                    android:maxLines="1"
                                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                    android:textSize="12sp"
                                    android:textStyle="normal"
                                    />
                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <com.spoof.app.customcontrol.CustomButtonRegular
                                android:id="@+id/btnOnSale"
                                style="@style/MyCustomButton"
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/round_button_progress_bar"
                                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                                android:text="@string/on_sale"
                                android:textAllCaps="false"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:textStyle="normal"
                                android:visibility="gone"
                                />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/linearGift"
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/round_button_progress_bar"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:visibility="gone"
                                >

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_gift"
                                    />


                            </LinearLayout>


                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgSpoofImage"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearBack"
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgBack"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_close_2"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearShare"
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgShare"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <com.spoof.app.customcontrol.CustomButtonRegular
                        android:id="@+id/btnOnSaleImage"
                        style="@style/MyCustomButton"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_margin="15dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_button_progress_bar"
                        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                        android:paddingRight="4dp"
                        android:text="@string/on_sale"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearGiftImage"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_margin="15dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_button_progress_bar"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_margin="8dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_gift"
                            />


                    </LinearLayout>


                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearTop"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        >

                        <com.spoof.app.customcontrol.CustomTextViewLight
                            android:id="@+id/txtComment"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                            android:textAllCaps="false"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorCrownBlack"
                            android:textSize="32sp"
                            />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            >

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imgCrown"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                />

                            <com.spoof.app.customcontrol.CustomTextViewLight
                                android:id="@+id/txtTotalSpoof"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:textAllCaps="false"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorCrownBlack"
                                android:textSize="13sp"
                                />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/relativeMain"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            >

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/relativeImage"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                >

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/imgProfileBG"
                                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                                    android:layout_height="73dp"
                                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                    />

                                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
                                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                                    app:civ_border_width="4dp"
                                    />
                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <com.spoof.app.customcontrol.CustomTextViewMedium
                                android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeImage"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:textAllCaps="false"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorDarkGray"
                                android:textSize="18sp"
                                />

                            <com.spoof.app.customcontrol.CustomTextViewRegular
                                android:id="@+id/txtTrendTime"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/txtUserName"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeImage"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:text=""
                                android:textAllCaps="false"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorLoginText"
                                android:textSize="12sp"

                                />

                            <com.spoof.app.customcontrol.CustomButtonRegular
                                android:id="@+id/btnFollow"
                                style="@style/MyCustomButton"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:background="@drawable/round_button_light_gray"
                                android:text="@string/following"
                                android:textAllCaps="false"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorCrownBlack"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:textStyle="normal"
                                android:visibility="gone"
                                />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>


                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/linearTop"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_separador"
                        />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <!-- <View
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="1.5dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                     android:background="@color/colorGray"
                     />
                     -->


            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rclTrendDetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearHome"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_round_button_spoof"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/rclTrendDetail"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_crownmenu"
            />

        <com.spoof.app.customcontrol.CustomTextViewMedium
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/iSpoofear"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorDarkGray"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Image Before Scroll

[image]

Image After Scroll

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you get the fix ? Me also having the same issue !

Answer (score 0):

just try to stop recyclerView effect on its parent by this when recyclerView Is empty:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: But i have not used toolbar as you given in answer.

Comment: still scroll up i think collapsing toolbarlayout scroll i have disable this but my last linear layout android:id="@+id/linearHome" not visible if am stop collapsing toolbar layout  scroll